# Google Sheets formula to compare data in a single cell with multiple cells and return a value based on those cells

Tags: google-sheets, formula, lookup

Currently, I have sheets document that compares cell name containing a last name field with a column of data elsewhere and returns a third column's value when it matches.  I have posted an example below

i.e.

Here is the formula ||| Lookup(A1,'Sheet 2'!B:B,'Column C'!C:C)

```
Sheet One with Formula              Sheet 2:
Column A    Column B                Column A    Column B    Column C
Smith       111111                  Oscar       Smith       111111
```

The problem is if there are 2 smiths it only grabs the first one.

What I want to do is use the first initial. last name in sheet one and compare to column A and B to return Column C.

```
Sheet One with Formula              Sheet 2
Column A    Column B                Column A    Column B    Column C
O. Smith    111111                  Alex        Smith       222222
                                    Oscar       Smith       111111
```

I am stuck...
Here is a link to help out. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m087VIKk_F8OUbKy2wMvb12DM9fg9r0YIlbU24QHsSY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried adding a third column in sheet two, to concatenate the two names into the item I was searching for, but the lookup failed for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B3 of Sheet 1 I entered this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A3:A), vlookup(A3:A, {Left(Sheet2!A2:A)&". "&Sheet2!B2:B, Sheet2!C2:C}, 2, 0),))
```

See if that works for you ?

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can you explain why your used LEN and what function that is doing in the formula?

Comment: I used LEN to 'limit' the vlookup range to the cells with content in col A (cells with content have a LENgth).

Answer (score 0):

JPV also informed me that Lookup requires content to be in alphabetical order. If I would have used Vlookup I could have pulled the data using the concatenation method I was trying out.

Concatenation formula: =Left(A2,1)&". "&B2

Working Formula - vlookup(A1,'Sheet 2'!B:B,'Column C'!C:C)

```
Sheet One with Formula      Sheet 2:
Column A    Column B        Column A    Column B    ColumnC     Column D
A. Smith    222222          Oscar       Smith       O.Smith     111111
                            Anthony     Smith       A. Smith    222222
```